# IOS in app purchases - should I use it or not

Tags: ios

I’ve a question about in app purchase.
I’ve an app to publish on the App Store and we are selling two plan of coaching services. User can unlock content from application AND access to external services like custom email with coaching advise, private community about our system
Must we used in app purchase in this case or a third party library ?

Comment: In this case, In-app purchase is the best way to go.

Comment: I think you would definitely need to use IAP for this since you are unlocking content in the app

Comment: And I have a second plan that offer multi level marketing. Example user take a subscription to 20$ and each time je sponsored an other user he win 5$. 
To ourchase this subscription plan In app purchase is mandatory too ?